# Can node.js replace Ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js

I'd like to know if it's possible to create a complete website using node.js (just like we do using Sinatra and Rails).

Also, is there any framework as good as Sinatra and Rails?

Is this the best use for node?

Regards.

Comment: I think you should definitely change the subject of this question; you can't compare an evented framework for Javascript with a general-purpose programming language.

Comment: Considering js has a lot more exposure and familiarity with developers(for ruby developer and non ruby developers), I feel this is highly likely.  Implement a sql back end and a little templating and it could potentially take off.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Express](http://github.com/visionmedia/express) is a framework much like Sinatra based off of Node.js.  It can be used to build an entire website, with complex routing and all the jazz.  I don't know if this is the best use for Node, but it is possible.

Answer (score 10):

No, node.js can't replace ruby.  You'd have trouble writing most of the scripts I regularly write in Ruby using node.js (even disregarding the difficulty of running them on my local machine).

Now, on the other hand, if you'd asked "Can node.js replace Rails/Sinatra/etc?", the answer might be quite different.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible but very hard too...programming in node.js is programming at low level..if you haven't good knowledge about javascript, ajax, etc, It will be almost impossible..

neither node.js as express are replaces for sinatra or rails...theses have other niche..while rails and sinatra are utils for create medium or big sites, node.js, express, faye..etc..are utils for create small but fast web apps...create a big site or complicate site using node is similar to cut your veins

Answer (score 1):

**Ralis**

If you want a full website, you should go for Rails. Ruby will help you build big websites in short time. Rails is in many ways "magical". That is, you might write a single line in Rails that ends up doing quite a lot, which for some is a good thing

**Express**

Express is just a skeleton framework. It kind of just provides the routing, and you can use your choice of tools to build whatever you want with it.

**Sinatra**

Sinatra is somewhat like express. It's a thin framework that will provide you the basic routing functionality and helper classes. You can any of the available `gems` to create your application.

**Restify**

For building APIs on NodeJS, you can use this amazing framework called restify

**So yea, ruby can indeed be replaced by nodeJS, but it will require developers more qualified in javascript, as large codebases, often get difficult to maintain.**