# Thoughts on using express.js instead of Ruby on Sinatra?

Tags: javascript, ruby, node.js, sinatra, express

I'm working on a social app and considering using express.js/nodejs instead of my original choice, Sinatra/Ruby.

I'm mostly worried about the # of open source projects available in Ruby to help get things done quickly. The second major concern is the stability/maturity and completeness of express.js.

Any feedback, comments are welcome.

Answer (score 42):

Hopefully this answer will help you out.  I tried to do something similar this weekend.  Being a long-time supporter of `Rails` (and after becoming pretty good at `Rails 3.2.1`, I decided to jump ship this weekend and switch to `Nodejs`.  Being an average JavaScript coder, I thought this would be fun and challenging.

I even bought a Nodejs screencast from Peepcode.  So, I sit down, fire up Textmate, get a simple nodejs project going, then tweak around with Twitter Bootcamp and the app is starting to look amazing, IMHO.

Then, I get to adding database support.  Then BAM.  Things hit me fast.  I have to find a non-blocking Postgresql driver.  Fine.  Found one.  What?  I have to manually create SQL queries?  But I'm so spoiled to ActiveRecord?  OK, there appears to be AR type frameworks for node.  But the tutorial I was using was for Express.  But wait, Nodejitsu recommended Flatiron.  OK, Flatiron looks promising.  But wait, I start looking at the example Flatiron uses for data management. They call it "Resourceful"?  I found one example of data management about a wolf eating a squirrel?  Where are the `has and belongs to many` examples?  How do I tell Flatiron that my `Notes` model is polymorphic and it belongs to `Trips` and `Expenses`?

I'm sure they're out there, but I couldn't find it.

But it gets better.  Shoot.  I thought I hated migrations until I had to fire up pgAdmin and/or Navicat to manually create my databases.  Then I had to manually create tables...oh crap.  I messed up a column in pgAdmin.  But it wouldn't let me change it!  So I had to restart the entire table creation again.  Ugh.  Man, I am missing generators and `rake db:migrate` at this point!

Then I realized that I spent the whole weekend (well, what little time I have for coding) and all I have to show for it is an awesome static HTML page that is non-functional.

Point is, if you are good at Rails, then Nodejs is going to be a major shift.  Maybe you like this?  Maybe not.

At the end of the weekend, I realized something.  My new app is going to be heavy on UI and is going to be sending JSON back/forth to the backend server.  Rails provides an excellent toolbelt for doing this.  Rails is perfectly happy speaking JSON.  In fact, my app is going to be static HTML pages served via nginx and Rails will drive the data layer with controllers.

My suggestion is learn Express/Nodejs if you want to start from scratch on every piece of the development process.  If you want to build your own query strings.  If you want do everything manually.  Maybe you like that.  Maybe you have ideas on making it easier for the world.  Maybe you want to use Tower.js or Flatiron.js or some other Nodejs framework.

Or, maybe you are like me and you have a damn app you want to finish.  Then use Rails.

Comment: I really have no experience in Node, but I feel like this response is misleading.  ActiveRecord is an ORM.  A Google of "Node js ORM" brought me straight to [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com/) which looks like it will do the trick.  There's also [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/) which eliminates the need of an ORM.

Comment: Further, the question was about Node.js vs Sinatra.. There was no mention of Rails.

Comment: The OP asked our "thoughts" on using Express vs. Ruby or Sinatra.  Granted, you don't have to use Rails when using Ruby but when I answered this (in 2012), Rails was a pretty big influence in the Ruby scene.  So, my intention was to relay my thoughts and experience (at the time) on developing a web application with a Node-based API.

Comment: @cbmeeks technically, the original question says Ruby **ON** Sinatra. Not ruby or Sinatra. Just clarifying that.

Answer (score 12):

There are already several (similar) questions regarding this topic:

- [Can node.js replace Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729568/can-node-js-replace-ruby)
- [Could node.js replace Ruby on Rails completely in the future?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436335/could-node-js-replace-ruby-on-rails-completely-in-the-future)
- [When to use node.js vs sinatra vs rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730309/when-to-use-node-js-vs-sinatra-vs-rails)

> I'm mostly worried about the # of open source projects available in
>   Ruby to help get things done quickly.

This is due to the fact that Ruby is much older than node.js. I think that more important than # of libraries is how much of them are built with non-blocking style. In case you are comparing Ruby and node.js then most of the modules in latter are built natively with this style since it's a nature of node.js.

> The second major concern is the stability/maturity and completeness of
>   express.js.

Although express is relativaly young compared to RoR or Sinatra, there are already [several applications](http://expressjs.com/applications.html) which were successfuly built on top of express.